# Can civil pilots *ever* fly military high-altitude penetration approach procedures?

Tags: iaps, ils

Let's say I'm flying some business types in a Gulfstream III (an approach category C aircraft) from Stockton to Palmdale to meet up with some USAF types there (new airplane deal, wooo!).  Can I accept/fly the HI-ILS approach to RWY 25 at KPMD:

[image: KPMD HI-ILS or LOC/DME RWY 25 approach plate[1]]

or am I only allowed to accept a STAR or vectors to a standard ILS approach to KPMD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you can actually make the altitude restrictions, then yes, there's no reason why you cannot request to fly the approach.  However, as a general courtesy, you should also factor in your approach speed.  ATC might not appreciate a Cessna clobbering the approach 34 miles out.  These approaches are typically flown at 250+kts, so just keep that in mind.

Comment: Depends on the Cessna -- a C172 would fly the ordinary ILS, but a C550 might fly the penetration procedure ;)

Answer (score 2):

Might check what descent rates would be required before trying it with passengers, but there shouldn't be any reason in principle that ATC couldn't clear you for that version of the ILS there.